# How does one do Algebra in Lua?

Tags: algorithm, lua, algebra

I've looked and tried but i cant find anything really helpful so thank you in advance.

My problem is i have a changing variable, "balance" for the moment i have it represented as 200. I need to use this equation to find how much money i should withdraw in a game, but I don't know how to write a LUA script that solves algebra

The equation is: `200/(x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5)=0.00001001` how would i set about solving for x?

I have tried adding .0000001 if 200/(x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5) doesn't equal 0.00001001 but it is very impractical and I haven't gotten it to work. This is The only way I can come up with at the moment. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You'll have to implement your own algorithm to solve it.

Comment: the "adding .0000001 if 200/(x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5) doesn't equal 0.00001001"? there's no other way?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintic_function

Comment: Why did i get a downvote for this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution finds zero of any continuous function (not only algebraical and not only differentiable) and requires knowing the diapazone of the root to be found.

```
local function find_zero(f, x_left, x_right, eps)
   eps = eps or 0.0000000001   -- precision
   local f_left, f_right = f(x_left), f(x_right)
   assert(x_left <= x_right and f_left * f_right <= 0, "Wrong diapazone")
   while x_right - x_left > eps do
      local x_middle = (x_left + x_right) / 2
      local f_middle = f(x_middle)
      if f_middle * f_left > 0 then
         x_left, f_left = x_middle, f_middle
      else
         x_right, f_right = x_middle, f_middle
      end
   end
   return (x_left + x_right) / 2
end


local function my_func(x)
   return 200/(x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5) - 0.00001001
end

-- Assuming that the root is between 1 and 1000
local x = find_zero(my_func, 1.0, 1000.0)
print(x)       -->  28.643931367544
```

Comment: id give ya an up vote but i dont have enough rep yet. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

200/(x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5)=0.00001001 is equivalent to 200 = 0.00001001 * (x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5), so you have a polynomial equation to solve, and traditionally it is this form of the equation that people like to deal with.

If you want to stay in Lua, then if the form of the equation is predictable enough that you can find a place where the right side is always less than the left (e.g. x = 0) and a place where the right sight is always greater than the left (e.g. very large values of x) then you can use binary search - not terribly efficient, but certain and easy to code.

For general polynomial equations, one well known method is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method. Given f(x) = 0 and a guess for x, a better guess might be x - f(x) / f'(x), where f'(x) is the derivative of f(x). There are a few pathological cases where this fails for various reasons, though, so again you probably want to know that your equations is reliably tractable.

Since you have Lua, you may be able to bring in C code that calls out to a maths library such as http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/. They have a routine called LaguerreSolver() which will reasonably reliably solve polynomial equations for you, defending itself against all of the pathological cases. Most math libraries contain a lot more work than any single person is likely to put in for an individual problem, and are of correspondingly higher quality than do it yourself approach such as I describe above.